# Laravel getAttribute not appended to the model

Tags: php, laravel

I have added a accessor to my User.php model `getArticlesCountAttribute`

```
    protected $appends = ['articles_count'];

    public function getArticlesCountAttribute()
    {
        return (int) $this->articles()->count();
    }
```

but when i access it from my laravel blade views articles count database query runs every-time i use the accessor in my view

For example: if i have `Auth::user()->articles_count` 3 times in my blade view it will run articles count query 3 times.

Shouldn't it be appended at the start and query should only run once no matter how many times i reference it in my views?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not cache or store it. It is still a model and a model should not have this kind of implementations.

You should restructure your view and pass the result of the count from the controller to the view.

```
public function myAction()
{
   return view('myview', [
      'articleCount' => Auth::user()->articles_count
   ]);
}
```

And in the view have than once the result in the variable $articleCount.

Comment: when we access relationships like `$user->articles` it gets cached, why not the same behaviour for attributes?

Comment: Caching is a diffrent thing than Active Record. If you want to have a Caching Layer you should implement something. You could use something like 

`$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function() {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one code

```
 protected $hidden = ['articles_count'];

public function getArticlesCountAttribute()
{
    return (int) $this->articles()->count();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could cache it, for example:

```
protected $articlesCounted;

public function getArticlesCountAttribute()
{
    if (is_null($this->articlesCounted)) {
        return $this->articlesCounted = $this->articles()->count();
    }
    return $this->articlesCounted;        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to access the attribute, not the method:

```
protected $appends = ['articles_count'];

public function getArticlesCountAttribute()
{
    return (int) $this->articles->count();
}
```

This way if articles is not loaded it will be the first time :)